# iwlwifi: Could not load the [0] uCode section; Failed to run INIT ucode: -5

Tags: intel, thinkpad, iwlwifi, microcode

I'm getting this error occasionally when my device wakes up from suspend,

```
iwlwifi: Log capacity -1515870811 is bogus, limit to 1 entries
iwlwifi: Log write index -1515870811 is bogus, limit to 1
iwlwifi: Start IWL Event Log Dump: display last 1 entries
wlp3s0: HW problem - can not stop rx aggregation for 9c:1c:12:24:0e:18 tid 0
iwlwifi: Command REPLY_ADD_STA failed: FW Error
wlp3s0: HW problem - can not stop rx aggregation for 9c:1c:12:24:0e:18 tid 1
p3s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=9c:1c:12:24:0e:18 reason=4 locally_generated=1
arn>  [1530059866.2378] sup-iface[0x5575dbb13da0,wlp3s0]: connection disconnected (reason -4)
ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested

... lots of stuff and a stack track

iwlwifi  iwl_trans_wait_tx_queues_empty bad state = 0
iwlwifi: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
iwlwifi: Could not load the [0] uCode section
iwlwifi: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
iwlwifi: Unable to initialize device.

... another stack trace,
```

I'm using this Wifi Card in a Lenovo x230 (from `lspci`, and `syslog`)

```
Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] (rev 34)
iwlwifi: Detected Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6205 AGN, REV=0xB0
```

I see a lot of errors pertaining to this card, but not with a failure to load uCode (microcode?) When things work, I see this in my `syslog`,

```
iwlwifi: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
iwlwifi: loaded firmware version 18.168.6.1 op_mode iwldvm
```

According to the [official Linux Wireless wiki](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi), I am running the latest version (`18.168.6.1`).

From all `syslog` messages PCI Address (`0000:03:00.0`) and timestamps cut out.