# Where can I find the microcode (ucode) that is being loaded by iwlwifi (Intel 6205)?

Tags: linux, networking, iwlwifi, microcode

Trying to [trouble-shoot this error](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/452122/iwlwifi-could-not-load-the-0-ucode-section-failed-to-run-init-ucode-5) which pertains to microcode, my card from `lspci` shows,

```
Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] (rev 34)
```

`system.log` shows,

```
iwlwifi: Detected Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6205 AGN, REV=0xB0
```

When I run `modinfo`, I get, (a lot of stuff cut off)

```
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
## lots of stuff...
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-6.ucode
## lots of stuff...
## NO iwlwifi-6205-#.ucode
srcversion:     6BA065AF04F0DFDB8D91DBF
```

But none of those show 6205. **Which `.ucode` is `system.log` referring to when it says,**

```
iwlwifi: loaded firmware version 18.168.6.1 op_mode iwldvm
```

There are two that I could assume,

```
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-6.ucode
```

But, is there way to know for certain?

Comment: `insmod` and some `sysdig` wizardry will probably reveal it in real time.

Comment: @don_crissti cool deal, cleaned it up. Thanks for being such a good sport.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is documented at the [Linux Wireless wiki](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#firmware):

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Device            | Kernel   | Module  | Firmware                             |
----------------- | ---------| ------- | ------------------------------------ |
 Intel® Centrino® | 2.6.36+  | iwldvm  | 17.168.5.1, 17.168.5.2 or 17.168.5.3 |
Advanced-N 6205   | -------- |         | ------------------------------------ |
                  | 3.2+     |         | 18.168.6.1                           |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This table reflects the minimal version of each firmware hosted at [linux-firmware.git](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git) repository that is known to work with that module and kernel version. In your specific case, the file is `iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode`.

`modinfo` will show all firmware files that can be used by that module(and that could support other hardware). The wireless wiki is a pretty reliable way to get information about hardware and firmware.

`dmesg | grep firmware` could help you on probing what firmware file is being used. Example 1 - firmware was loaded correctly:

```
[ 12.860701] iwlagn 0000:03:00.0: firmware: requesting lbm-iwlwifi-5000-1.ucode
[ 12.949384] iwlagn 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 8.24.2.12
```

Example 2 - missing firmware file `d101m_ucode.bin`:

```
[  77.481635] e100 0000:00:07.0: firmware: requesting e100/d101m_ucode.bin
[ 137.473940] e100: eth0: e100_request_firmware: Failed to load firmware "e100/d101m_ucode.bin": -2
```

Comment: That's a *much* better method, lol though I will leave mine up there for reference. And, I would love for this to be somewhere sane -- like in the system.log.

Comment: Old broadcom wifi user here so, this wiki was almost my homepage years ago. LOL. @EvanCarroll, added some probing with `dmesg`

Comment: And your answer is not stupid. Reading the source code is never stupid and you found what piece of code is responsible to make the decision of which firmware needs to be loaded with your specific hardware variant of this wifi card ;)

Answer (score 3):

[This answer is stupid, do this instead.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/452127/3285)

## Digging through the source

Down the rabbit hole. The only way I could find out for sure was to grep the source tree,

```
cd /tmp
apt source linux-modules-$(uname -r)
```

Then I went grepping for `Advanced-N 6205 AGN`,

```
rgrep -l 'Advanced-N 6205 AGN' ./linux-4.15.0/
./linux-4.15.0/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/cfg/6000.c
```

And, I checked out the `6000.c` which has a struct,

```
const struct iwl_cfg iwl6005_2agn_cfg = {
  .name = "Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6205 AGN"
  IWL_DEVICE_6005,
  .ht_params = &iwl6000_ht_params,
};
```

Looking up `IWL_DEVICE_6005`, I see it's a preprocessor define for

```
#define IWL_DEVICE_6005           \
  .fw_name_pre = IWL6005_FW_PRE,        \
  .ucode_api_max = IWL6000G2_UCODE_API_MAX,   \
  .ucode_api_min = IWL6000G2_UCODE_API_MIN,   \
  .device_family = IWL_DEVICE_FAMILY_6005,    \
  .max_inst_size = IWL60_RTC_INST_SIZE,     \
  .max_data_size = IWL60_RTC_DATA_SIZE,     \
  .nvm_ver = EEPROM_6005_EEPROM_VERSION,    \
  .nvm_calib_ver = EEPROM_6005_TX_POWER_VERSION,  \
  .base_params = &iwl6000_g2_base_params,     \
  .eeprom_params = &iwl6000_eeprom_params,    \
  .led_mode = IWL_LED_RF_STATE,       \
  .max_ht_ampdu_exponent = IEEE80211_HT_MAX_AMPDU_64K
```

Which the firmware name (`fw_name_pre`) is `IWL6005_FW_PRE` is

```
#define IWL6005_FW_PRE "iwlwifi-6000g2a-"
```

So, I guess the actual *right* answer to this question is

```
iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode
```

And the version is,

```
#define EEPROM_6005_EEPROM_VERSION  (0x709)
```

Answer (score 2):

While I feel the `dmesg` log is the best answer for tracing loading a firmware file, there is an alternative method to trace all the files opened in a certain timeframe. I will leave here for the sake of completeness.

You can always use a realtime tracing tool capable of following kernel calls as `sysdig`.

So after installing it with

```
sudo apt-get install sysdig
```

Here you have the trace of all the files opened by a Debian 9 VM after I inserted my ralink wifi USB pen. Unfortunately there are no firmware files, as otherwise they would appear in the example.

The sysdig script format is flexible enough for narrowing down data, users and file names as needed for debug purposes:

```
$sudo sysdig -p "%12user.name %6proc.pid %12proc.name %3fd.num %fd.typechar %fd.name" evt.type=open 
root         339    systemd-udev 12  f /run/udev/queue
root         1483   systemd-udev 6   f /proc/self/oom_score_adj
root         1483   systemd-udev 6   f /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:02.0/usb1/1-1/uevent
root         1483   systemd-udev -1  f /run/udev/data/c189:1
root         1483   systemd-udev 6   f /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:02.0/usb1/1-1/descriptors
root         1483   systemd-udev 6   f /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:02.0/usb1/1-1/idVendor
root         1483   systemd-udev 6   f /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:02.0/usb1/1-1/idProduct
root         1483   systemd-udev 6   f /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:02.0/usb1/1-1/manufacturer
root         1483   systemd-udev 6   f /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:02.0/usb1/1-1/product
root         1483   systemd-udev 6   f /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:02.0/usb1/1-1/bcdDevice
root         1483   systemd-udev 6   f /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:02.0/usb1/1-1/serial
root         1483   systemd-udev 6   f /proc/cmdline
root         1483   systemd-udev 6   f /run/udev/data/.#c189:1PS1U2W
root         1483   systemd-udev 6   f /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:02.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/uevent
root         1483   systemd-udev -1  f /run/udev/data/+usb:1-1:1.0
root         1483   systemd-udev 6   f /proc/cmdline
root         1483   systemd-udev 6   f /run/udev/data/.#+usb:1-1:1.0W1sYYW
root         1483   systemd-udev -1  f /sys/module/rt2800usb/initstate
root         1483   systemd-udev 6   f /sys/module/usb_common/initstate
root         1483   systemd-udev 6   f /sys/module/usbcore/initstate
root         1483   systemd-udev -1  f /sys/module/rfkill/initstate
root         1483   systemd-udev 6   f /lib/modules/4.9.0-6-amd64/kernel/net/rfkill/rfkill.ko
root         1483   systemd-udev -1  f /sys/module/crc_ccitt/initstate
root         1483   systemd-udev 13  f /lib/modules/4.9.0-6-amd64/kernel/lib/crc-ccitt.ko
root         1483   systemd-udev -1  f /sys/module/cfg80211/initstate
root         1483   systemd-udev 14  f /lib/modules/4.9.0-6-amd64/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
root         1486   systemd-udev 6   f /proc/self/oom_score_adj
root         1486   systemd-udev 6   f /sys/devices/virtual/misc/rfkill/uevent
root         1484   systemd-udev 6   f /proc/self/oom_score_adj
root         1484   systemd-udev -1  f /sys/module/rfkill/uevent
root         1484   systemd-udev -1  f /run/udev/data/+module:rfkill
root         1484   systemd-udev 6   f /proc/cmdline
root         1485   systemd-udev 6   f /proc/self/oom_score_adj
root         1486   systemd-udev -1  f /run/udev/data/c10:56
root         1486   systemd-udev 6   f /proc/cmdline
root         1486   systemd-udev 6   f /run/udev/data/.#c10:56fjUFaV
root         1485   systemd-udev -1  f /sys/class/rfkill/uevent
root         1485   systemd-udev -1  f /run/udev/data/+class:rfkill
root         1485   systemd-udev 6   f /proc/cmdline
root         1487   systemd-udev 6   f /proc/self/oom_score_adj
root         1487   systemd-udev -1  f /sys/module/crc_ccitt/uevent
root         1487   systemd-udev -1  f /run/udev/data/+module:crc_ccitt
root         1487   systemd-udev 6   f /proc/cmdline
root         1488   systemd-udev 6   f /proc/self/oom_score_adj
root         1488   systemd-udev -1  f /sys/module/cfg80211/uevent
root         1488   systemd-udev -1  f /run/udev/data/+module:cfg80211
root         1488   systemd-udev 6   f /proc/cmdline
root         1485   systemd-udev -1  f /sys/class/ieee80211/uevent
root         1485   systemd-udev -1  f /run/udev/data/+class:ieee80211
root         1485   systemd-udev 6   f /proc/cmdline
root         1485   systemd-udev 6   f /sys/devices/platform/regulatory.0/uevent
root         1485   systemd-udev -1  f /run/udev/data/+platform:regulatory.0
root         1485   systemd-udev 6   f /proc/cmdline
root         1485   systemd-udev 6   f /sys/devices/platform/regulatory.0/uevent
root         1485   systemd-udev -1  f /run/udev/data/+platform:regulatory.0
root         1485   systemd-udev 6   f /proc/cmdline
root         1483   systemd-udev -1  f /sys/module/mac80211/initstate
root         1483   systemd-udev 15  f /lib/modules/4.9.0-6-amd64/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
root         1485   systemd-udev -1  f /sys/module/mac80211/uevent
root         1485   systemd-udev -1  f /run/udev/data/+module:mac80211
root         1485   systemd-udev 6   f /proc/cmdline
root         1483   systemd-udev -1  f /sys/module/rt2x00lib/initstate
root         1483   systemd-udev 16  f /lib/modules/4.9.0-6-amd64/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ralink/rt2x00/rt2x00lib.ko
root         1485   systemd-udev -1  f /sys/module/rt2x00lib/uevent
root         1485   systemd-udev -1  f /run/udev/data/+module:rt2x00lib
root         1485   systemd-udev 6   f /proc/cmdline
root         1483   systemd-udev -1  f /sys/module/rt2800lib/initstate
root         1483   systemd-udev 17  f /lib/modules/4.9.0-6-amd64/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ralink/rt2x00/rt2800lib.ko
root         1485   systemd-udev -1  f /sys/module/rt2800lib/uevent
root         1485   systemd-udev -1  f /run/udev/data/+module:rt2800lib
root         1485   systemd-udev 6   f /proc/cmdline
root         1483   systemd-udev -1  f /sys/module/rt2x00usb/initstate
root         1483   systemd-udev 18  f /lib/modules/4.9.0-6-amd64/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ralink/rt2x00/rt2x00usb.ko
root         1485   systemd-udev -1  f /sys/module/rt2x00usb/uevent
root         1485   systemd-udev -1  f /run/udev/data/+module:rt2x00usb
root         1485   systemd-udev 6   f /proc/cmdline
root         1483   systemd-udev -1  f /sys/module/rt2800usb/initstate
root         1483   systemd-udev 19  f /lib/modules/4.9.0-6-amd64/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ralink/rt2x00/rt2800usb.ko
root         1485   systemd-udev -1  f /sys/module/rt2800usb/uevent
root         1485   systemd-udev -1  f /run/udev/data/+module:rt2800usb
root         1485   systemd-udev 6   f /proc/cmdline
root         1485   systemd-udev -1  f /sys/module/arc4/uevent
root         1485   systemd-udev -1  f /run/udev/data/+module:arc4
root         1485   systemd-udev 6   f /proc/cmdline
root         1485   systemd-udev 6   f /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:02.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/ieee80211/phy0/uevent
root         1485   systemd-udev -1  f /run/udev/data/+ieee80211:phy0
root         1485   systemd-udev 6   f /proc/cmdline
root         1488   systemd-udev 6   f /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:02.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/net/wlan0/uevent
root         1488   systemd-udev -1  f /run/udev/data/n3
root         1488   systemd-udev 6   f /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:02.0/usb1/1-1/idVendor
root         1488   systemd-udev 6   f /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:02.0/usb1/idVendor
root         1488   systemd-udev 6   f /proc/cmdline
root         1488   systemd-udev 6   f /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:02.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/net/wlan0/address
root         1488   systemd-udev 6   f /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:02.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/net/wlan0/type
root         1488   systemd-udev 6   f /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:02.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/net/wlan0/ifindex
root         1488   systemd-udev 6   f /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:02.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/net/wlan0/iflink
root         1488   systemd-udev 6   f /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:02.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/net/wlan0/addr_assign_type
root         1484   systemd-udev 6   f /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:02.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/leds/rt2800usb-phy0::radio/uevent
root         1484   systemd-udev -1  f /run/udev/data/+leds:rt2800usb-phy0::radio
root         1484   systemd-udev 6   f /proc/cmdline
root         1487   systemd-udev 6   f /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:02.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/leds/rt2800usb-phy0::assoc/uevent
root         1487   systemd-udev -1  f /run/udev/data/+leds:rt2800usb-phy0::assoc
root         1487   systemd-udev 6   f /proc/cmdline
root         1486   systemd-udev 6   f /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:02.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/leds/rt2800usb-phy0::quality/uevent
root         1486   systemd-udev -1  f /run/udev/data/+leds:rt2800usb-phy0::quality
root         1486   systemd-udev 6   f /proc/cmdline
root         1483   systemd-udev -1  f /sys/bus/usb/drivers/rt2800usb/uevent
root         1483   systemd-udev -1  f /run/udev/data/+drivers:usb:rt2800usb
root         1483   systemd-udev 6   f /proc/cmdline
root         1485   systemd-udev 6   f /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:02.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/ieee80211/phy0/rfkill0/uevent
root         1485   systemd-udev -1  f /run/udev/data/+rfkill:rfkill0
root         1485   systemd-udev 6   f /proc/cmdline
root         1488   systemd-udev 6   f /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:02.0/acpi_index
root         1488   systemd-udev 6   f /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:02.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/net/wlan0/dev_port
root         1488   systemd-udev 6   f /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:02.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/net/wlan0/phys_port_name
root         1488   systemd-udev 6   f /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:02.0/config
root         1488   systemd-udev 6   d /sys/bus/pci/slots
root         1488   systemd-udev 13  f /sys/bus/pci/slots/230/address
root         1488   systemd-udev 13  f /sys/bus/pci/slots/55/address
root         1488   systemd-udev 13  f /sys/bus/pci/slots/259/address
root         1488   systemd-udev 13  f /sys/bus/pci/slots/164/address
root         1488   systemd-udev 13  f /sys/bus/pci/slots/45/address
root         1488   systemd-udev 13  f /sys/bus/pci/slots/192/address
root         1488   systemd-udev 13  f /sys/bus/pci/slots/35/address
root         1488   systemd-udev 13  f /sys/bus/pci/slots/63/address
root         1488   systemd-udev 13  f /sys/bus/pci/slots/229/address
root         1488   systemd-udev 13  f /sys/bus/pci/slots/53/address
root         1488   systemd-udev 13  f /sys/bus/pci/slots/257/address
root         1488   systemd-udev 13  f /sys/bus/pci/slots/162/address
root         1488   systemd-udev 13  f /sys/bus/pci/slots/43/address
root         1488   systemd-udev 13  f /sys/bus/pci/slots/33/address
root         1488   systemd-udev 13  f /sys/bus/pci/slots/61/address
root         1488   systemd-udev 13  f /sys/bus/pci/slots/227/address
root         1488   systemd-udev 13  f /sys/bus/pci/slots/51/address
root         1488   systemd-udev 13  f /sys/bus/pci/slots/199/address
root         1488   systemd-udev 13  f /sys/bus/pci/slots/160/address
root         1488   systemd-udev 13  f /sys/bus/pci/slots/41/address
root         1488   systemd-udev 13  f /sys/bus/pci/slots/263/address
root         1488   systemd-udev 13  f /sys/bus/pci/slots/225/address
root         1488   systemd-udev 13  f /sys/bus/pci/slots/197/address
root         1488   systemd-udev 13  f /sys/bus/pci/slots/58/address
root         1488   systemd-udev 13  f /sys/bus/pci/slots/261/address
root         1488   systemd-udev 13  f /sys/bus/pci/slots/167/address
root         1488   systemd-udev 13  f /sys/bus/pci/slots/48/address
root         1488   systemd-udev 13  f /sys/bus/pci/slots/195/address
root         1488   systemd-udev 13  f /sys/bus/pci/slots/38/address
root         1488   systemd-udev 13  f /sys/bus/pci/slots/231/address
root         1488   systemd-udev 13  f /sys/bus/pci/slots/56/address
root         1488   systemd-udev 13  f /sys/bus/pci/slots/165/address
root         1488   systemd-udev 13  f /sys/bus/pci/slots/46/address
root         1488   systemd-udev 13  f /sys/bus/pci/slots/193/address
root         1488   systemd-udev 13  f /sys/bus/pci/slots/36/address
root         1488   systemd-udev 13  f /sys/bus/pci/slots/54/address
root         1488   systemd-udev 13  f /sys/bus/pci/slots/258/address
root         1488   systemd-udev 13  f /sys/bus/pci/slots/163/address
root         1488   systemd-udev 13  f /sys/bus/pci/slots/44/address
root         1488   systemd-udev 13  f /sys/bus/pci/slots/34/address
root         1488   systemd-udev 13  f /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:02.0/config
root         1488   systemd-udev 6   f /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:02.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/uevent
root         1488   systemd-udev 6   f /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:02.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/bInterfaceNumber
root         1488   systemd-udev 6   f /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:02.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/bInterfaceClass
root         1488   systemd-udev 6   f /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:02.0/usb1/1-1/uevent
root         1488   systemd-udev 6   f /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:02.0/usb1/1-1/descriptors
root         1488   systemd-udev 6   f /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:02.0/usb1/1-1/idProduct
root         1488   systemd-udev 6   f /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:02.0/usb1/1-1/manufacturer
root         1488   systemd-udev 6   f /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:02.0/usb1/1-1/product
root         1488   systemd-udev 6   f /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:02.0/usb1/1-1/bcdDevice
root         1488   systemd-udev 6   f /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:02.0/usb1/1-1/serial
root         1488   systemd-udev 6   f /run/udev/data/+usb:1-1:1.0
root         1488   systemd-udev 6   f /run/udev/data/.#n3eBu1Pw
root         1494   systemd-udev 6   f /dev/null
root         1494   ifupdown-hot 3   f /etc/ld.so.cache
root         1494   ifupdown-hot 3   f /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
root         1494   ifupdown-hot 3   f /lib/udev/ifupdown-hotplug
root         1494   ifupdown-hot 3   f /dev/null
root         1494   ifupdown-hot 3   f /dev/null
root         1485   systemd-udev -1  f /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:02.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/net/wlan0/queues/rx-0/uevent
root         1485   systemd-udev -1  f /run/udev/data/+queues:rx-0
root         1485   systemd-udev 6   f /proc/cmdline
root         1484   systemd-udev -1  f /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:02.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/net/wlan0/queues/tx-1/uevent
root         1484   systemd-udev -1  f /run/udev/data/+queues:tx-1
root         1484   systemd-udev 6   f /proc/cmdline
root         1487   systemd-udev -1  f /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:02.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/net/wlan0/queues/tx-2/uevent
root         1487   systemd-udev -1  f /run/udev/data/+queues:tx-2
root         1487   systemd-udev 6   f /proc/cmdline
root         1486   systemd-udev -1  f /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:02.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/net/wlan0/queues/tx-3/uevent
root         1486   systemd-udev -1  f /run/udev/data/+queues:tx-3
root         1486   systemd-udev 6   f /proc/cmdline
root         1488   systemd-udev -1  f /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:02.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/net/wlan0/queues/tx-0/uevent
root         1488   systemd-udev -1  f /run/udev/data/+queues:tx-0
root         1488   systemd-udev 6   f /proc/cmdline
root         1495   ifupdown-hot 0   f /dev/null
root         1497   grep         3   f /etc/ld.so.cache
root         1497   grep         3   f /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3
root         1497   grep         3   f /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
root         1497   grep         3   f /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
root         1497   grep         3   f /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
root         1496   ifquery      3   f /etc/ld.so.cache
root         1496   ifquery      3   f /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
root         1496   ifquery      3   f /etc/network/interfaces
```

We can double confirm with `lsmod` output the kernel modules loaded:

```
$lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
arc4                   16384  2
**rt2800usb**              28672  0
**rt2x00usb**              24576  1 rt2800usb
**rt2800lib**              94208  1 rt2800usb
**rt2x00lib**              53248  3 rt2800lib,rt2800usb,rt2x00usb
**mac80211**              671744  3 rt2800lib,rt2x00lib,rt2x00usb
**cfg80211**              589824  2 rt2x00lib,mac80211
crc_ccitt              16384  1 rt2800lib
**rfkill**                 24576  1 cfg80211
sysdig_probe          430080  0
vmw_vsock_vmci_transport    28672  1
vsock                  36864  2 vmw_vsock_vmci_transport
softdog                16384  0
loop                   28672  0
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
vmw_balloon            20480  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
intel_rapl_perf        16384  0
sg                     32768  0
vmw_vmci               69632  2 vmw_balloon,vmw_vsock_vmci_transport
button                 16384  0
ext4                  585728  1
crc16                  16384  1 ext4
jbd2                  106496  1 ext4
crc32c_generic         16384  0
fscrypto               28672  1 ext4
ecb                    16384  0
mbcache                16384  2 ext4
sd_mod                 49152  4
crc32c_intel           24576  0
aesni_intel           167936  0
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
gf128mul               16384  1 lrw
ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 24576  3 ablk_helper,ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
ehci_pci               16384  0
ehci_hcd               81920  1 ehci_pci
usbcore               253952  4 rt2800usb,rt2x00usb,ehci_hcd,ehci_pci
usb_common             16384  1 usbcore
e1000                 143360  0
mptspi                 24576  3
scsi_transport_spi     32768  1 mptspi
mptscsih               32768  1 mptspi
mptbase                77824  2 mptscsih,mptspi
scsi_mod              225280  5 sd_mod,mptscsih,scsi_transport_spi,sg,mptspi
```